# Setting Discontinuous Bounds for an Optimization model with scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy

I have an optimization program which is working fine, however there are some additional boundary conditions I need to implement.  At the moment the boundaries look like this:

```
bnd1 = (50000, 160000)
bnd2 = (357116, 1271242)
bnd3 = (5047, 336340.29)
bnd4 = (11621, 124680.49)
bnd5 = (3655, 521087.8102)
bnd6 = (13145, 347950.8542)
```

The optimization should be able to take any value between these points, but 0 is also a value it should be able to take!  Is there some sort of if/or constraint I can introduce to get around this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Please show us some relevant code. Right now we don't even know what kind of optimization we're talking about (convex, discrete, etc).

Comment: 2^6=64... why not testing all the possibilities? unless one optimization takes already one hour...